# Obtener valor de un partialview en la vista padre

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

en realidad, tengo dos preguntas para hacerles relacionadas con las partialview.

Primero, les voy a comentar como es que muestro la partialview

**Pregunta Uno**

**Agregar.cshtml**

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Suma)

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("PartialGrupoConexion", Model.conexionadoviewmodel); }
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ese es el método por el cual abro un modal con una partialview dentro, la primer pregunta es la siguiente.

**¿Es este el mejor método de utilizar un partialview?** (dentro de un modal claro está)

¿O sería mejor usar jQuery y Ajax para insertarle los datos del partialview al modal?

**Pregunta Dos**

Mi segundo problema respecto a los partialview, es que no comprendo cual sería el método para obtener información de estos desde una vista normal, voy a usar un ejemplo de mi problema intentando que se interprete de la manera más sencilla.

En la vista principal (**Agregar.cshtml**) poseo un EditorFor que utiliza el campo Suma del Modelo.

Y teniendo un partialview similar a esto

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.PrimerElemento)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SegundoElemento)

<button type="button">Calcular</button>
```

Lograr devolver la suma de estos dos campos a la vista principal, tenía unas ideas para hacerlo con JQuery, pero al parecer no debo utilizarlo dentro de un PartialView

**EDIT** 
Los viewmodel serían algo así

```
public class Principal
    {
        public int suma { get; set; }
        public int resta { get; set; }
        public SumaPartialView SumaParcial{ get; set; }
    }
    public class SumaPartialView
    {
        public int valor1 { get; set; }
        public int valor2 { get; set; }
        public int suma { get; set; }
    }
```

Espero haberme expresado bien, desde ya muchísimas gracias por la buena onda!

Comment: Aclaro que quiero utilizar **PartialView** porque es un procedimiento que tengo que realizar en muchísimos lugares dentro del proyecto, y de esta manera poder reutilizar el código

Comment: lo pudiste solucionar? tengo el mismo problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mejor metodo seria solo enviando los datos mediante json y asignando estos a los controles que ya definas en el html del popup. En lugar de retornar html, retornas json.

Como se explica en el articulo:

[CRUD Operations In MVC Using Jquery Ajax | Part-2 Create PopUp Modal With Registration Form](http://abctutorial.com/Post/31/crud-operations-in-mvc--using-jquery-ajax)

Pero igual la forma que lo implementas tambien es valida.

Desde la vista principal solo podras acceder a la info de popup usando `jquery`, no se realiza desde `razor`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la data!

Comment: El enlace es muy útil, sin embargo te recomiendo que extraigas un ejemplo a partir de ese enlace, de tal manera que en caso el enlace se rompa, la documentación queda en tu respuesta. Saludos :D